# Help with cross-referencing an equation

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

I am trying to learn how to use the `\eqref` commands instead of just doing `tag{1.1}`, so I don't have to go back and renumber. I'm having trouble: in problem 3b, I say

`Now 
 \eq{y(t, \epsilon)= y_0(t) + \epsilon y_1(t) + O(\epsilon^2), \label{eq:aa}}`

(\eq is an abbreviation I've defined, it is `\newcommand{\eq}[1]{\begin{align*}#1\end{align*}}`). Later I go back and write `So we can fill in \eqref{eq:aa}`, and the problems are

1. It doesn't label the equation
2. When it refers back to it, it calls it (1.2), although it is the
   first tagged equation.

Here is a link to my code, if it helps you diagnose. https://www.writelatex.com/read/zjhhjpndjpkz

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Please make a small self contained document that shows the problem and add it to the question (not as a link)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My problem is that I'm not sure where the problem is...if I try to recreate the problem from scratch it shows up the right way. What would you recommend?

Comment: Start from a copy of your document and delete anything you can delete while still showing the problem: if you delete something and the problem goes away then that's the cause of the problem. Once you can make the document no smaller, post it here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK, will do.

Comment: it's absolutely necessary that we see the definition of `\eq`.  the application of the label (and the printing of the equation number) is defined in `equation`, so if that is "broken", it would explain why there's nothing to reference.

Comment: This is going to be interesting with David and Barbara here, I've always wondered what defining those very usual and simple commands would/could cause.  Eric, I strongly suggest using the auto-completion feature of your favorite editor. Even the non-GUI ones come with them I'm sure (just saying in case you use one of them).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

okay.  here are some problems with your definition.

*any* starred math display environment is intended to suppress numbering.  you can put a `\tag{...}` on a starred environment, but the number won't be incremented automatically.  however, a `\label` on such a tag *will* be honored by `\ref` or `\eqref`.  (all `\eqref` really does is format the argument of a `\ref` to be upright and wrapped in parentheses.)

next. `align` is intended to be used for multi-line expressions with each line having a left and a right part.  although a lot of people use `\align` for one-line displays, it's a bad idea, since the vertical spacing around a multi-line display is intentionally different from that around a one-line display.  and if there aren't two parts to a line (separated by `&`), the structure won't be centered horizontally.

finally, turning environments into commands makes your input much more difficult for someone else to read and decipher, and leads to bad input habits -- like running display material into long lines.  believe me, this leads to serious loss of hair on the part of journal editors.

if you really want a one-line, numbered display using a shorthand like this, it can be done, perhaps like this:

```
\newcommand{\eq}[1]{\begin{equation} #1\end{equation}}
```

but it's better to think twice before doing so.  someone suggested persuading your input environment/editor to use "completion".  this makes for *much* more scrutable files, and more efficient debugging and maintenance in the long run.

Comment: I'd like to upvote this answer many times ...

Answer (score 2):

I've taken a look at the code you provide in the link. The main problem, it would seem, is that you use the `align*` environment in the definition of the `\eq` macro. The `align*` environment, by design, does *not* increment or print equation numbers. Hence, any `\label` instruction associated with this equation (or group of equations) will not point to what's generated by `\eq`.

As a result, a subsequent `\ref` or `\eqref` instruction won't point to that structure. Instead, either `(??)` will be printed out, or the cross-reference will point to the object that had its associated counter incremented most recently before the lost `\label` instruction. This object could be a section, a theorem, some other equation that was generated the "normal" way (i.e., not via `\eq`), etc.

You should be able to achieve a better outcome by defining the `\eq` macro as follows:

```
\newcommand{\eq}[1]{\begin{equation}\begin{split} #1 \end{split}\end{equation}}
```

and affix a `\label` instruction to it, as in

```
\eq{y(t, \epsilon)= y_0(t) + \epsilon y_1(t) + O(\epsilon^2),} \label{eq:aa}
```

Note that with this setup, you should rename all `\tag` instructions inside an `\eq` statement with `\label`.

Comment: Thanks for the input! What is `split` doing here?

Comment: @EricAuld - The nested `equation` and `split` environments act a bit like an `align` environment, while assigning a single equation number to the entire group. The inner, `split` environment lets you provide alignment points à la `align`.